# How to resolve a Capacitor WebSocket error connection in Angular/Ionic?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, amazon-ec2, capacitor

I´m trying to run in **Android Studio** an app made with **Angular/Ionic** that connects with an Api located in a **instance of EC2**, the app works perfectly well in the QA environment using the command **"ionic serve"**.

But when running it in **Android Studio** and emulate it in a virtual device, it get me the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dACNb.png)

I never configured a WebSocket and the connection with the Api is through URL:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: "http://16.171.27.66:8090/api/v0"
};
```

How can i remove this webSocket or configure it to resolve the error?

This is my **capacitor.config.ts** file:

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'io.ionic.starter',
  appName: 'App_ColocarUk',
  webDir: 'www',

  server: {
    androidScheme: 'https',
  },
};

export default config;
```